# Portable firewall rules for Linux and Free/Net/Open/DragonFlyBSD

Tags: linux, firewall, freebsd, openbsd, netbsd

I need apply the same rules (lists of IPs with allow and drop rules) in firewalls of Linux and *BSD. Do you know some application (CLI) for to convert a list of rules in the specific format of each firewall?.

The application for to convert the rules is only a idea. Other solutions for the problem are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.fwbuilder.org/

> Firewall Builder supports a wide range of firewall platforms, including Cisco ASA & PIX, Linux iptables, BSD pf and many more. You’re not confined to one platform—or locked into a single vendor.

See the intro: http://www.fwbuilder.org/4.0/docs/firewall_builder_intro.html

Comment: Thanks. I know the tool but I need a CLI application.

Comment: Why? Fwbuilder doen't have to be on the actual firewall.  You can prepare the rules on a workstation.  I haven't really used it much, but it is an open souce project.  You may be able to extract the conversion features...

Comment: Because is for an automatic script and the rules will be in a central server. I don't need extract the conversion code, I think the conversion is easy but I would like a well tested tool.

Comment: It (at least v5) has a cli: http://www.fwbuilder.org/4.0/man1/fwbedit.1.html

Answer (score 1):

Such conversion is not always possible, since different packet filters have different logic and packet processing scheme. For example, there is no simple and straight way to convert iptables rules (with all those tables and chains) to ipfw or pf rules. It's better to just write new ruleset for needed firewall type with knowing what you need to get in the end.

Comment: Good point. I only need convert lists of IPs and rules like allow and drop. No more.

Comment: in such case it should be pretty easy to write simple shell-script for conversions.

Comment: Yes, I asked for a existing solution but is not a difficult task.